# lambdas throwing error inside a user defined macro

Tags: lambda, macros, racket

I defined the following macro...

```
(define-syntax >> ;;compose
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(>> f1 [args ...]) 
     (lambda (x) (f1 args ... x))]
    [(>> f1 [args1 ...] f2 [args2 ...] rf ...) 
     (>> (lambda (x) (f2 args2 ... (f1 args1 ... x)) ) rf ... )]
    [(>> f1 [args1 ...] f2  rf ...) 
     (>> (lambda (x) (f2 (f1 args1 ... x)) ) rf ...)]
    [(>> f1 f2 [args2 ...] rf ...) 
     (>> (lambda (x) (f2 args2 ... (f1 x)) ) rf ...)]
    [(>> f1 )           
     (lambda (x) (f1 x))]
    [(>> f1 f2 rf ...) 
     (>> (lambda (x) (f2 (f1 x))) rf ...)]))
```

To help me write functions in this fashion:

```
(define composed-function (>> (lambda (x) (+ x 1))  (lambda (x) (+ x 1))))
```

The thing is, everything works fine with named functions, but when i use lambdas as portrayed in the example above, i get an error of the kind "lambda: bad syntax in lambda", any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your macro is falling into the wrong pattern. You *think* it should be applying this one:

```
[(>> f1 f2 rf ...) 
 (>> (lambda (x) (f2 (f1 x))) rf ...)]))
```

But in actuality it can actually match this pattern:

```
[(>> f1 [args ...]) 
 (lambda (x) (f1 args ... x))]
```

with `f1` matching `(lambda (x) (+ x 1))`, and `(args ...)` matching `(lambda (x) x)`. Which expands to:

```
 (lambda (x) ((lambda (x) (+ x 1)) lambda (x) x x))
```

Which is gibberish. You're probably better off with a pattern that requires parens around each argument:

```
(define-syntax >> ;;compose
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(>> (f1 args ...)) 
     (lambda (x) (f1 args ... x))]
    [(>> (f1 args1 ...) (f2 args2 ...) rf ...) 
     (>> (lambda (x) (f2 args2 ... (f1 args1 ... x)) ) rf ... )]))
```

Which also reduces the number of arguments you need. To use it, do:

```
(define composed-function (>> ((lambda (x) (+ x 1)))  ((lambda (x) (+ x 1)))))
```

Of course, a third option is just to use [`compose`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=compose#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._compose%29%29) from `racket/base`. It admittedly doesn't let you pass in fixed arguments for each function, but you can still get that with eta-expansion.

To use `compose` your example would look like:

```
(define composed-function (compose (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) (lambda (x) (+ x 1))))
```

(Note though that the functions are reversed from your example.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i had the feeling it was something along those lines, i know this is another question but you seem to know what you are talking about, so, is there a way to check the types of the patterns to be more precise?, or maybe a way to dispatch the syntax to another pattern match from within the body of the expression that finally returns a syntax object?

Comment: Yes there is. The easiest way to 'dispatch' to another pattern is to just use the macro again in the template. The easiest way to find information on the syntax 'type' is to use the `syntax/parse` library. Unfortunately there's not enough space in a comment to go over example, but its worth opening a new question for that. :)